# Blackberry Jar file Error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

My app cod size is 90kb and when compiling it, it gives run time error

> Error: jar command failed: jar -cfm "E:\Blackberry Workspace\Kenexa\deliverables\Standard\7.1.0\Kenexa.jar" C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local ...  
>   Packaging project Kenexa failed (took 9.129 seconds)

I have set the classpath in the system variable but its not the path problem I think, its related to the cod size I guess. When I delete any class or when the cod file size shrinks to 89kb then it runs. How to get this problem sovled?

Comment: How are you building your app?  From the normal BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin?  From the legacy RIM JDE?  Please don't apply both the `blackberry-eclipse-plugin` tag, and the `blackberry-jde` tag to your question, unless you have tried building in **both** IDEs, and are getting the same exact error.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I used: BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin And Okay, Do you know its solution?